# React Typescript - Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-xoktyd?file=Form.tsx)

It's a React app using Typescript and hooks to capture entries into form that are simple displayed below.

Here in Stackblitz it works but locally I am using VS code and I get an error for `setUser(userData);` the error is

```
const userData: {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    prevState: null;
}
Argument of type '{ username: string; password: string; prevState: null; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(prevState: null) => null'.
  Type '{ username: string; password: string; prevState: null; }' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: null): null'.ts(2345)
```

How can I fox this typescript error

Comment: Did  [none of these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Argument+of+type+is+not+assignable+to+parameter+of+type+%5Breactjs%5D+%5Btypescript%5D) answer your question?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
```

Since you havn't given this a type, typescript has to try to infer it. It sees you passed in a null, so it assumes this state is (and always will be) null. Instead, you need to specify the type, as in:

```
interface UserData {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  prevState: null
}

//...
const [user, setUser] = useState<UserData | null>(null);
```

Comment: And if you are using this `user` state variable anywhere in your application then you will need to add some kind of guard statement like `if (!user) return;` or `user?.someProperty ... `

Answer (score 51):

If you fetching data from API you need this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

const MyComponent = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState<any | null>(null);
const fetchData = () => {
(...) //Axios.get() or async if u await data.
setData(fetchData)
}
}
useEffect(() =>{
    fetchData()
}, [])
```

Comment: `useState<any | null>` can be simplified to `useState<any>`